# custom post type without single view

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom type 'movies', which basically shows a list of movies where each links directly to an external website, then, I see that when I create a movie a permalink is created to display /films/film_name

Is there any possibility that the type does not create that url for the single view of item?

In resume, I have this:

/movies/movie-1 /movies/movie-2 and so...

But I want only 
/movies directory 
because I dont use the single page for each movie.

Is 301 redirect for each movie to /movies directory the only possibility?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Updated:

The solution that I "implemented" was as simple as possible. In single-movies.php I put a 301 redirect to /movies/

Comment: Can you elaborate more. Its unclear to me.

Comment: sure... now you understand?

Comment: So you need `/movies` instead of `/movies/movie-1` even if you're in single page?

Comment: Yes, that is. Something like this:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/custom-post-type-no-need-for-single-view-plus-want-permalink-rewrites-that-inc

Comment: That answer isn't helpful to you?

Comment: See the question update. Think you that is ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a 301 in your custom single.php, and wrap get_permalink function with filter like that :

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
if ( $post->post_type == 'movie' ) {
    $url = get_post_meta($post-ID, 'YOUR_CUSTOM_LINK', true);
}
return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3 );
```